# Can you add input data with a token transfer?

Tags: web3js, tokens

I was successfully able to send eth with some message here: 0x4ea3d0ae060aeb08f41fb8ff3e468b7e44092a251ccef118b386136fe6427a64 (little tackier though). I did this from MEW, but saw that it is not possible to send input data with a token transfer. I know the token transfer has instructions for the token smart contract in the same input data field. So does that mean we cannot send a message (input data) with a token transfer and it is only possible on ETH transfer? Not familiar enough with web3 to figure this out on my own. Really appreciate if anyone can share their know-how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the token is ERC20 compliant, then no, the normal transfer functions don't have a field for extra data.

As seen in the [ERC20 standard here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard#The_ERC20_Token_Standard_Interface), the two functions for transferring tokens are defined as

```
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
```

and

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
```

neither of which have a field for extra data. However, the standard does not forbid a token from having *extra* functions, so the particular token contract with which you are dealing may have a transfer function with an extra data field. You'd need to view the contract code to know if this was the case.